# How to make the default selection of a value in sql out of multiple choices?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my SQL table i.e. `Gender` and there can be one of two possible values for it, 'M' and 'F'.

For those values, I am able to pass two values by using a check constraint as option when creating the table:

```
Gender varchar(6) CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'F'))
```

Also, one of those value is defined as the default:

```
Gender varchar(6) DEFAULT 'M'
```

But here, if I am trying to merge those two queries while table creation, I am not getting the output. I want to pass two choices for column value and default as 'M'.

Comment: I am querying over ssms using microsoft sql server. Its latest version of sql server. I want to create choice column in a table with default value.

Comment: Good luck building a system which only handles 2 genders. And if you have to, wouldn't it make more sense to use a `bit` column?

Comment: @DaleK A `bit` column and a `char(1)` take the same amount of space. And I think OP is using "gender" as a proxy for "sex" (as people often do), for which you could *"conceivably"* split into `M` `F`, and `NULL` for indefinite.

Comment: @Charlieface IMH bit is more intuitive than a char(1) with constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both can be used as part of the *create table* syntax:

```
create table t(gender char(1) default('M') check(gender in ('M','F')));
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03a2d5c7a244c07c355b2fdd66b794a1)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use both in the `CREATE TABLE` statement - and preferably, define *explicit* names for your constraints!

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT CHK_Person_Gender CHECK (Gender IN ('M', 'F'))
        CONSTRAINT DF_Person_Gender DEFAULT ('M')
)
```